# Function in R with loops

Tags: r

```r
binary_subset<-function(a){
  a_seq = lapply(a, seq, 0)   # keep 0s as 0, make 1s c(1, 0)
  subset=do.call(expand.grid, a_seq)
  colnames(subset)=(1:length(a))
  print(subset)
}

a<-c(0,0,1,0)
b<-c(1,0,0,0)

inter_a<-binary_subset(a)
inter_b<-binary_subset(b)
interactions_ab<-rbind(inter_a,inter_b)
interactions_no_duplicate<-unique(interactions_ab[1:length(a)])


> interactions_no_duplicate
  1 2 3 4
1 0 0 1 0
2 0 0 0 0
3 1 0 0 0


inter_no_duplicate<-function(a,b){

inter_a<-binary_subset(a)
inter_b<-binary_subset(b)
interactions_ab<-rbind(inter_a,inter_b)
interactions_no_duplicate<-unique(interactions_ab[1:length(a)])

interactions_no_duplicate
}



> inter_no_duplicate(a,b)
  1 2 3 4
1 0 0 1 0
2 0 0 0 0
  1 2 3 4
1 1 0 0 0
2 0 0 0 0
  1 2 3 4
1 0 0 1 0
2 0 0 0 0
3 1 0 0 0
```

I am trying to write is function to get some binary interactions. First I wrote the code in a simple straightforward form and get my desired output. But, when I put everything inside a function, the output is not the same. It includes some extra rows (though my desired outputs are there!). The last 3 rows of the second output is my answer which matches exactly with the first output. why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: I have edited my code. You can now copy and paste! it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `return(subset)` or just `subset` at the bottom of your function `binary_subset`, like

```
binary_subset <- function(a) {
  a_seq <- lapply(a, seq, 0) # keep 0s as 0, make 1s c(1, 0)
  subset <- do.call(expand.grid, a_seq)
  colnames(subset) <- (1:length(a))
  return(subset)
}
```

or a shorter one

```
binary_subset <- function(a) {
  a_seq <- lapply(a, seq, 0) # keep 0s as 0, make 1s c(1, 0)
  `colnames<-`(do.call(expand.grid, a_seq),1:length(a))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

R functions return the last line like in your `inter_no_duplicate()` function, or what is in `return()` (`return(interactions_no_duplicate)`).

You ask `binary_subset()` to print *subset*, so it prints it in console. `inter_no_duplicate()` call two times `binary_subset()`, so you have two prints before `interactions_no_duplicate` data.
If you try `test <- inter_no_duplicate(c(0, 0, 1, 0), c(1, 0, 0, 0))`, you will see the two prints in console and `test` will be the data you want.

Remove `print()` or keep it if you want to print it in console, but at least add `return(subset)` at the end to `return()` data or variables.